# Escape special character in postgresql

Tags: java, jdbc, escaping, expression

I have below string in the postgres database

> `ABC 123 !#$%*&'-(,)^?<\>~(())%%\\'',,//##$--++**??&&@!!~~\\`

Ii want user to be able to search these special characters when they input from screen. However, the program keep throwing error. I use string to create the query (this is the framework nature so i cannot change => Cannot use PreparedStatement), so this problem happen. I tried the below method and it seem that this function can resolve some special characters but when i input `[@#$%*&'-(,)^?<\>~(())]` from the screen and start searching, it throw `org.seasar.extension.jdbc.IllegalBindArgSizeRuntimeException`

```
private String replaceSpecialCharacter(String str) {
    String strResult = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
     strResult = strResult.replaceAll("%", "\\\\\\\\\\\\%");

     strResult = strResult.replaceAll("％", "\\\\\\\\\\\\％");
     strResult = strResult.replaceAll("_", "\\\\\\\\\\\\_");
     strResult = strResult.replaceAll("＿", "\\\\\\\\\\\\＿");
     strResult = strResult.replaceAll("'", "\\\\\\\\\\\\'");
     strResult = strResult.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\"");

     return strResult;
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, but it resolved for \, %, _, \ character. But i don't know how to go with the others

Comment: Drop this idea. Fix your framework and use a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks all, i decided to remove ? mark from the parameter before assigning to SQL. This resolved the problem